# Under extrusion

Tags: prusa-i3, slic3r, underextrusion

I have a Prusa i3 3D printer and am using Slic3r for slicing.

I've noticed that my extruder is underextruding. I've correctly set the nozzle diameter and the filament diameter and I've already tried to increment the extrusion multiplier (which is currently set to 1.1). As Slic3r suggests this is a maximum value, I'm wondering if there is something else wrong.

Does anybody a have suggestions on which settings I can look at?

[image]

Comment: It looks like your nozzle is just too far from the bed. Reset the extrusion multiplier to 1.0 and level your bed. Alternatively (or perhaps also) did you configure the filament diameter wrong in slic3r?

Comment: If that was the cause, it would only happen on the lowest layer. However, this error occurs on all levels. I measured the filament diameter with calipers on multiple places and configured this value.

Comment: Make sure the extrusion width is set absolutely, or is set to 0. Slic3r (and PrusaSlicer) has a bug where extrusion width is calculated over layer height if set as a percentage.

Comment: Is the next layer properly extruded? Also, are you printing on cloth?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Prusa i3 pro b, and was having a similar issues. Turns out the spring for the plastic extruder feeder can be too slack. I printed [these](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1936289) at 2 mm and put it under the spring and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the nozzle is too far from the bed, try leveling the bed again - that should solve the problem.

Comment: The nozzle is already fairly close to the bed. Also, this problem doesn't only occur on the lowest layer. For example, vertical walls also very easily split because the different lines of the perimeter don't connect.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be, that your hotend temperature is too low and the extruder 'spins through', so that too little filament is extruded. In that case you would hear some clicking noise.

Comment: The hotend temperature is currently set to 180degrees for PLA filament. I don't hear a clicking noise during printing...

Comment: I do print PLA on my Prusa i3 pro C with 240°C and it extrudes very well, the clicking noise only appeared at high feedrates for me but the extrusion often was too low at lower temperatures. Just do a bit of trial with the temperature.

Comment: Btw I use curaengine in Repetier host as slicer an set the extrusion of the first layer to 40% because the nozzle is as near to the bed, that just a piece of paper fits under it with some friction.